# how to split file txt to array in java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, split

hello guys how to split  String from file txt

for example  i have file 
server.txt

```
192.168.1.2,80
192.168.1.3,3306
```

then i want split a  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3  to String[] ipserver
and then split 80,3306 String[] port
and the output print all array ipserver and print all array port
this my code:

```
String csvFile = "c:/Users/user/Desktop/in.txt";
    String line = "";



    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] ipserver = line.split(";|,");
            String[] port = line.split(",|;");  
                    System.out.println( ipserver[i] );
                    System.out.println( port[i] );


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

please help me guys  to split , thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
List<String> ipServerList = new LinkedList();
List<String> portList = new LinkedList();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(";|,")
    ipServerList.add(values[0]);
    portList.add(values[1]);
}
String[] ipServers = ipServerList.toArray(new String[ipServerList.size()]);
String[] ports = portList.toArray(new String[portList.size()]);
```

We create two `List`s in which we store the values. At the end we convert them to arrays

Comment: [answer] XXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print along the way of splitting the string ..

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] ipNport = line.split(","); 
            System.out.println( ipNport[0] );
            System.out.println( ipNport[1] );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
String toSplit = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\in.txt")).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
           String[] ipserver = null, port = null;

        ArrayList<String> ipServerAl = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> portAl = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ipPortPairList = toSplit.split("\\r\\n");

    for (String ipPortPair : ipPortPairList) {
        ipServerAl.add(ipPortPair.split(",")[0]);
        portAl.add(ipPortPair.split(",")[1]);
    }

    ipserver = ipServerAl.toArray(new String[ipServerAl.size()]);
    port = portAl.toArray(new String[portAl.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Understand how to use split function of String. Visit below link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

2.

a. If you just want to print to console, Follow @Rakibul Haq's answer.

b. If you want to store/process it some point later, follow @Shanu gupta's answer.
b. if you are reading it from a CSV file. Use apache poi library:
https://poi.apache.org/ (I think you are a novice in Java, so this might be difficult at least for now)

c. Reading from a .txt file. You have done it right. Congrats!

Below is a working code:

```
package com.bt.neweserve.agent.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

    public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String csvFile = "c:/Users/611654029/Desktop/in.txt";
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        // Using lists from Collections framework. Note: Dynamic array. Size is not
        // defined, it is dynamic.
        List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> portList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] result = line.split(",");
            ipList.add(result[0]);
            portList.add(result[1]);
        }

        br.close();
        System.out.println("Using dynamic array ie ArrayList");
        System.out.println(ipList);
        System.out.println(portList);

        // using array. Size is defined/constant.

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] ipListArray = new String[10]; // assuming you have 10 lines in the file.
        String[] portListArray = new String[10];

        int i = 0; // Initial index of the array.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] result = line.split(",");
            ipListArray[i] = result[0];
            portListArray[i] = result[1];
            i++; // Note the increment of array index
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Using static array i.e. array of predefined size");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ipListArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(portListArray));
    }
    }
```

Hope this helps.